# I keep on getting the error: redefinition of 'i' when I run this code. Misunderstanding of local variables

Tags: c++

This is a question from the book I am learning c++ from. It just says:

6.21- Identify and correct the errors int he following program:

```
void p(int i)

{
    int i = 5;
    cout << "i is " << i << endl;

}
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with this code. I think it probably has to do with the argument of p. When I try to build it in sublime text it says 
"error: redefinition of 'i'"

If it helps, we are learning about local, static and global variables.

Thanks!

Comment: Please choose a meaningful title related to the problem you're having. This makes questions more easily searchable and more useful for other users. "Identify and correct errors in the following code" is very generic and gives no relevant information wrt to the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

The code is in violation of the C++11 standard Fourth edition 2014-12-15 (and previous versions but this is the one I have readily available). Specifically, section 3.3.3 paragraph 2, which states:

"The potential scope of a function parameter name (including one appearing in a lambda-declarator) or of a function-local predefined variable in a function definition (8.4) begins at its point of declaration. If the function has a function-try-block the potential scope of a parameter or of a function-local predefined variable ends at the end of the last associated handler, otherwise it ends at the end of the outermost block of the function definition. A parameter name shall not be redeclared in the outermost block of the function definition nor in the outermost block of any handler associated with a function-try-block."

The last sentence states the requirement.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By declaring `int i = 5`, you're attempting to introduce a new variable into a scope that already has one with that name (from the parameter list). That's an error.

It is impossible without any context to arbitrarily "fix" the function, but you could varyingly:

- remove `int i = 5`
- remove the parameter `int i`
- rename either

Answer (score -1):

There are two conflicting `i`, so the parameter will always be ignored.

This function will always print out "i is 5" no matter what value is passed into the function.

Comment: @O'Brien                  

So because p(int i) takes int i as a parameter but is also defining int i =5 as a local variable, this is where the conflict is?

Comment: Correct. This is an example of "shadowing".

Comment: gcc considers this an error (no warnings turned into errors) and won't compile. In that case at least, it won't print anything. What decided to compile it for you?

Comment: -1: Wrong for the reason Alex stated. This is not shadowing: you're attempting to introduce a new variable into a scope that already has one with that name. That's an _error_.

Comment: Well, the compile error that g++ gives to the above code is `error: declaration of ‘int i’ shadows a parameter`, so it seems reasonable to call it "shadowing".

Comment: @EamonnO'Brien-Strain: The message is misleading. It would be "shadowing" if you did it in such a way that the program were actually valid (such as by introducing a new, encapsulated block scope). Shadowing is valid. This program is not.

Comment: @AlexM. What do you mean "what decided to compile it for you"? I was just running this program since it's an example of the book.

thanks for your help!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So this code is wrong because I'm trying to create two variables in the same scope with the same name, which is not allowed. Right?

Comment: @the_answer_is_dont: Right. BTW Alex was talking to Eamonn, not you.

Comment: @Lightness, I agree that calling this "shadowing" is a bit misleading, because shadowing usually refers to declarations in overlapping scope, which is allowed.

Comment: FWIW, clang doesn't call it shadowing: error: redefinition of 'i'. Less confusing, I guess.